# Itunes run whenever the windows start, how to block no run?

Tags: itunes

After install itunes, it starts whenever the window start, How can I block?

I tried , msconfig -> start program -> disable itunes help

Installed ccleaner disable apple on startup

disable some apple service on msconfig

I checked every option on itunes setting

but never works , itunes run and pop up always..

Comment: Do you have plex media server?  or any other software that autostarts that would want iTunes to be running? i.e. something besides windows is starting it.  Enabling preferences > advanced > "share iTunes library xml with other applications" may stop it from autostarting.

Comment: @Tyson You got it Yeah I have plex server Never thought it cause itunes problem I will try it Thx!! Plz add this as answer so that I can accept later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A third party application is likely starting iTunes.  (such as plex media server)

Beginning with iTunes 12.2 the Library.XML file is no longer automatically generated. Enabling preferences > advanced > "share iTunes library xml with other applications" seems to solve the problem of some third party applications starting iTunes.  Apparently if the XML file is not present then the 3rd party application opens iTunes to access the library, if the XML is present there is no need to open iTunes.

Apple didn't explain this change well, and in fact the option isn't even included in the iTunes help file yet (at least windows iTunes help). Instead Google "share iTunes library xml with other applications" to learn more.